# Changing value of an object array with formbuilder

Tags: angular, formbuilder, angular2-formbuilder

I am having problem with formbuilder in angular 2. I have the following scenario.

I am validating an email, if I already have within the array of employees I clean the field, if it is allowed do nothing. I'm running a foreach to check this, in my constructor I create the formbuild and the referent part looks like this:

[image]

The object I add relating to demand is thus.

[image]

I put a blur event in the input and execute this function.

```
public verifyEmail(employee_email: string, index) {
  if (employee_email === '') {
    return;
  }

  let ocorrency = 0;
  this.formOrganization.value.employees.forEach(employee => {
    if (employee.email === employee_email) {
      ocorrency += 1
    }
  });

  if (ocorrency >= 2) {
    this.messageNotify(false, 'email_already_exists');
    this.formOrganization.get('employees')[index].patchValue({'email': ''});
  }
}
```

For the function to send 2 parameters, the first is the email that I need to test and the second the index that refers to which object within the array I am working on, it is in this index that I need to zero the field.

How to do this ?

My html is:

```
        <div class="col-md-12 col-12 tabs-content" *ngIf="membersTabs">
      <div class="row" formArrayName="employees">
        <div class="col-12">
          <button class="btn btn-new pull-left" (click)="addEmployeer()">Adicionar Membros</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12">
          <div class="card card-members"
               *ngFor="let employeer of formOrganization.controls.employees.controls; let index = index"
               [formGroupName]="index">
            <div class="card-header">
              <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-8">
                <strong class="text-capitalize">{{formOrganization.value.employees[index].first_name}}
                  {{formOrganization.value.employees[index].second_name}}</strong>
              </div>
              <div class="wrapper-switch col-sm-12 col-md-4">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
                    <button class="btn btn-new btn-transparent" *ngIf="formOrganization.value.employees[index]._id"
                            (click)="[changePasswordSelected(employeer.value), passwordModal.show()]">ALTERAR SENHA
                    </button>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
                    <button class="btn btn-cancel" (click)="removeEmployeer(index)">Remover</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-block">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 form-group">
                  <label class="col-md-10 form-control-label">Primeiro Nome</label>
                  <div class="col-md-12">
                    <input class="form-control " name="first_name" type="text"
                           formControlName="first_name">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 form-group">
                  <label class="col-md-10 form-control-label">Sobrenome</label>
                  <div class="col-md-12">
                    <input class="form-control " name="second_name" type="text"
                           formControlName="second_name">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 form-group">
                  <label class="col-md-10 form-control-label">Cargo</label>
                  <div class="col-md-12">
                    <input class="form-control " name="office" type="text" formControlName="office">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-6 col-sm-12 form-group">
                  <label class="col-md-10 form-control-label">Acesso</label>
                  <div class="col-md-12">
                    <select class="form-control modal-input" id="access" name="access" formControlName="access">
                      <option value="">Selecione a opção</option>
                      <option *ngFor="let item of accesss"
                              [selected]="item.name == employeer.value.access.name"
                              [ngValue]="item">{{item.name}}
                      </option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-1 col-sm-12 form-group">
                  <label class="col-md-10 form-control-label">Status</label>
                  <div class="col-md-12">
                    <label class="switch switch-text switch-pill switch-primary">
                      <input type="checkbox" class="switch-input " formControlName="status">
                      <span class="switch-label" data-on="On" data-off="Off"></span>
                      <span class="switch-handle"></span>
                    </label>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 form-group">
                  <label class="col-md-10 form-control-label">Email</label>
                  <div class="col-md-12">
                    <input class="form-control " name="email" type="text" formControlName="email"
                           (blur)="verifyEmail(formOrganization.value.employees[index].email, index)">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-5 col-sm-12 form-group"
                     *ngIf="!formOrganization.value.employees[index]._id">
                  <label class="col-md-10 form-control-label">Senha</label>
                  <div class="col-md-12">
                    <input class="form-control " name="password" type="password"
                           formControlName="password">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

My form from formBuilder:

[image]

Comment: It is not very clear what you want to achieve and/or where the issue is. Are you not able to get the index as the second parameter?

Comment: Agreed w/ @P.Moloney - if you're calling `(blur)="verifyEmail()"` from your component template, you should likely be able to pass in the index from your html, after declaring it with `let i=index` in your `*ngFor` statement. But we'll have to see your template HTML, if that is the issue.

Comment: My problem is happening because I want to clear my field, I need to set a value in the field, with model would be easy to do so: myModel = "the string I want" but I'm using formBuilder and besides I can have 0, 1 or infinitor employees.

Comment: I added my html in the question, although it is not related to it. Again the problem is that I am trying to clear the field.

Comment: your issue is not very clear, why don't you clear your email field by passing empty string or null to your form element. you have formControlName thus, whatever value you will set in your ts file for that element in the form, html would display

Comment: Exactly this is not giving. I have a formControlName yes, but I do not have 1, I have several, this is array how will I know which one I will change? Show me an application of my case, how to access to change the value. I can not apply it .. It's something so simple that I can not do it and not explain it for what it seems.

Comment: I updated my question with all my formBuilder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to clear you field you can use [patchValue](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#patchvalue) to change one element of your form and that will change your input field as well

```
this.formOrganization.patchValue({
  email: ''
});
```

**Update**

If email is under employess you can still use patchValue for nested array. you can pass the value and index in your blur event

```
<label class="center-block">email:
            <input class="form-control" #email formControlName="email" (blur)="test(email.value,i)">
          </label>


test(value, index){
let x = <FormArray>this.heroForm.get('employees');
let y =   (<FormControl>x.controls[index])

y.patchValue({
  email: ''
})

}
```

you can get index from *ngFor on employees, let i=index

Comment: try updated answer, i tried in plunker and it works!

Comment: Ufa ! Thank you very much!